# .NET client calling HTTPS Java web service

Tags: c#, .net, client, java-ws

I have a HTTPS Java Web Service, I am trying to access the web service with .NET[.NET 2.0 style client / WCF client]. I am getting back this error from WS.

"HTTP Status 401 - This request requires HTTP authentication ()."

How do I find out what kind of security this WS has?
Besides SSL, I have user name and password to send it to WS, I believe this is part of message authentication.

Java client seems like successfully communicating, and it has few interesting lines,

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", new String(jsseKeyStorePassword));
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", new String(jsseTrustStorePassword));

----------------------------------------------

  BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, new String(password));
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I had nothing but headaches when working with a Silverlight client (granted it was version 2) in conjunction with an Axis2 WS...tread carefully...

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, 
Two problems I had to solve,

1. HTTP Status 401 - This request
   requires HTTP authentication ()

   > Changed Authentication schema to Basic in the VS generated customeBinding in app.config
2. HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not
   Supported

   > Remove **Expect: 100-continue**  SOAP header. Add this line `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`. For the details of the issue, <strike>go here</strike>

Long story here http://www.irasenthil.com/2010/10/wcf-client-to-java-web-service.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the Java WS requires a server and root certificate stored in a couple of key stores. It requires knowledge of the passwords to these key stores to obtain the certificates, which seem to be available in the `jsseKeyStorePassword` and `jsseTrustStorePassword` variables.

Also, you should be using at least .NET Framework 3.0 in order to use Windows Communication Foundation.

Comment: Mhm, I meant .NET 2.0 style client or WCF client